# Running Jetty 7 as Windows Service

Tags: windows, service, jetty

Did Jetty 7 drop support to run as a service using Java Service Wrapper?
What options do I have now?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

@glb, thanks for pointing out apache commons-daemon Procrun.
Its working great for me on Windows 7 64 Bit, here's how I set it up.

For more info see

- [procrun](http://commons.apache.org/daemon/procrun.html) page as per link from @glb
- jetty help screen > java -jar start.jar --help

---

```
REM 1. Open command prompt as Administrator

mkdir C:\java\apache-commons-daemon
REM 2. Download commons-daemon binaries for windows to directory above from
REM      http://www.apache.org/dist/commons/daemon/binaries/windows/commons-daemon-1.0.15-bin-windows.zip
REM 3. unzip which will create C:\java\apache-commons-daemon\commons-daemon-1.0.5-bin-windows

mkdir C:\java\jetty
REM 4. Download jetty to directory above from
REM      http://download.eclipse.org/jetty/7.4.2.v20110526/dist/jetty-distribution-7.4.2.v20110526.zip 
REM 5. install / unzip which will create C:\java\jetty\jetty-distribution-7.4.2.v20110526

REM 6. Verify that jetty can be started
cd C:\java\jetty\jetty-distribution-7.4.2.v20110526
java -jar start.jar
REM     Look for any obvious errors on the console
REM     Open a browser at http://localhost:8080/
REM     You should be presented with the Jetty Start Page,
REM      and be able to execute the Hello World Servlet
REM     OK, that's enough,
REM      come back to the command prompt and ctrl-C to stop the jetty server

REM 7. Copy and rename commons-daemon binaries into the JETTY_HOME directory structure
REM     Note that the GUI manager is copied to JETTY_HOME,
REM      and the service exe is copied to JETTY_HOME\bin
REM     Note that both binaries get the same target name,
REM      but are placed in different directories
REM     This is just makes it easier to launch the GUI manager
REM      by not having to provide command line arguments
REM     Note that I have selected the amd64\prunsrv.exe as the service exe,
REM      I am running on Windows 7 64 bit Intel i7 Xeon
cd C:\java\jetty\jetty-distribution-7.4.2.v20110526
copy \java\apache-commons-daemon\commons-daemon-1.0.5-bin-windows\prunmgr.exe .\JettyService.exe
copy \java\apache-commons-daemon\commons-daemon-1.0.5-bin-windows\amd64\prunsrv.exe .\bin\JettyService.exe

REM 8. Time to install the service
bin\JettyService //IS//JettyService --DisplayName="Jetty Service" --Install=C:\java\jetty\jetty-distribution-7.4.2.v20110526\bin\JettyService.exe --LogPath=C:\java\jetty\jetty-distribution-7.4.2.v20110526\logs --LogLevel=Debug --StdOutput=auto --StdError=auto --StartMode=Java --StopMode=Java --Jvm=auto ++JvmOptions=-Djetty.home=C:\java\jetty\jetty-distribution-7.4.2.v20110526 ++JvmOptions=-DSTOP.PORT=8087 ++JvmOptions=-DSTOP.KEY=downB0y ++JvmOptions=-Djetty.logs=C:\java\jetty\jetty-distribution-7.4.2.v20110526\logs ++JvmOptions=-Dorg.eclipse.jetty.util.log.SOURCE=true ++JvmOptions=-XX:MaxPermSize=128M ++JvmOptions=-XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled ++JvmOptions=-XX:+CMSPermGenSweepingEnabled --Classpath=C:\java\jetty\jetty-distribution-7.4.2.v20110526\start.jar --StartClass=org.eclipse.jetty.start.Main ++StartParams=OPTIONS=All ++StartParams=C:\java\jetty\jetty-distribution-7.4.2.v20110526\etc\jetty.xml ++StartParams=C:\java\jetty\jetty-distribution-7.4.2.v20110526\etc\jetty-deploy.xml ++StartParams=C:\java\jetty\jetty-distribution-7.4.2.v20110526\etc\jetty-webapps.xml ++StartParams=C:\java\jetty\jetty-distribution-7.4.2.v20110526\etc\jetty-contexts.xml ++StartParams=C:\java\jetty\jetty-distribution-7.4.2.v20110526\etc\jetty-testrealm.xml --StopClass=org.eclipse.jetty.start.Main ++StopParams=--stop

REM 9. Test that the service starts at the command prompt
bin\JettyService //TS

REM 10. To delete the service uncomment the line below
REM bin\JettyService //DS

REM 11. Now launch the GUI manager to check the parameter settings
JettyService.exe

REM You can use the GUI to start and stop the service, and to change the settings
REM If you want the GUI exe to have a different name to the service exe,
REM   then close the GUI and uncomment and run the line below
REM ren JettyService.exe JettyServiceMgr.exe
REM To launch the renamed GUI uncomment and run the line below
REM JettyServiceMgr.exe //ES//JettyService
```

---

done!

Comment: Thank you for the info. Just to let you know: for this to work properly, I had to set the JAVA_HOME environment variable.

Comment: The UI is especially helpful to double check what Java runtime is being used. And make sure JAVA_HOME is set in *System* environment variables, not user's ones. Otherwise, it all works for you, but not for the service.

Answer (score 3):

In the latest stable version of [Java Service Wrapper](http://wrapper.tanukisoftware.com/doc/english/download.jsp) (JSW 3.4.1) there's WrapperJarApp method of integration:

This is part of my configuration:

```
wrapper.java.mainclass=org.tanukisoftware.wrapper.WrapperJarApp
wrapper.java.classpath.1=%WRAPPER_HOME%/lib/*.jar
wrapper.java.classpath.2=%JETTY_HOME%/lib/*.jar
wrapper.java.classpath.3=%JETTY_HOME%/start.jar
wrapper.java.library.path.1=%WRAPPER_HOME%/lib
wrapper.app.parameter.1=%JETTY_HOME%/start.jar
wrapper.app.parameter.2=%JETTY_HOME%/etc/jetty.xml
# other config params as needed
```

Comment: In my initial tests with this, Jetty appears to work best if JSW is launched from `%JETTY_HOME%` (i.e. drop the JSW configs, jar and DLL into the Jetty install dir). This way if Jetty looks around for config settings relative to the current path the service is running from the expected location.

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at [Procrun](http://commons.apache.org/daemon/procrun.html) from the Apache Commons.  You'll want to browse the native binaries download area to get the Windows binaries.

Answer (score 2):

You can get the src from: http://svn.codehaus.org/jetty/jetty/branches/jetty-7/jetty-win32/ and build it yourself.

But I manually installed the wrapper as any “standard” wrapper installation.

Took the original Jetty-Service.conf file and changed:

wrapper.java.mainclass=org.mortbay.jetty.win32service.JettyServiceWrapperListener
to
wrapper.java.mainclass=org.tanukisoftware.wrapper.WrapperSimpleApp

And added…

wrapper.app.parameter.1=org.eclipse.jetty.start.Main <-- Main class
wrapper.app.parameter.2=../etc/jetty.xml
wrapper.app.parameter.x=../etc/jetty-x.xml <--Any additional config files you wish to include…
wrapper.app.parameter.y=../etc/jetty-y.xml

Seems to start fine and it seems to shutdown gracefully too.

Answer (score 2):

I had a problema running @crowne's code for install the service (I'm running Jetty 8.1.0). Just needed to change `-StartMode=Java --StopMode=Java`  to `-StartMode=jvm --StopMode=jvm` and remove `++JvmOptions=-XX:+CMSPermGenSweepingEnabled`.

After that I created a create_jetty_service.bat at the jetty/bin folder and run the file from there:

```
set jetty_home = C:\java\jetty\jetty-hightide-8.1.0.v20120127

JettyService //IS//JettyService --DisplayName="Jetty Service" ^
--Install=%jetty_home%\bin\JettyService.exe ^
--LogPath=%jetty_home%\logs ^
--LogLevel=Debug --StdOutput=auto --StdError=auto --StartMode=jvm --StopMode=jvm --Jvm=auto ^
++JvmOptions=-Djetty.home=%jetty_home% ^
++JvmOptions=-DSTOP.PORT=8087 ^
++JvmOptions=-DSTOP.KEY=downB0y ^
++JvmOptions=-Djetty.logs=%jetty_home%\logs ^
++JvmOptions=-Dorg.eclipse.jetty.util.log.SOURCE=true ^
++JvmOptions=-XX:MaxPermSize=256M ^
++JvmOptions=-XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled ^
--Classpath=%jetty_home%\start.jar ^
--StartClass=org.eclipse.jetty.start.Main ^
++StartParams=OPTIONS=All ^
++StartParams=%jetty_home%\etc\jetty.xml ^
++StartParams=%jetty_home%\etc\jetty-deploy.xml ^
++StartParams=%jetty_home%\etc\jetty-webapps.xml ^
++StartParams=%jetty_home%\etc\jetty-contexts.xml ^
++StartParams=%jetty_home%\etc\jetty-testrealm.xml ^
--StopClass=org.eclipse.jetty.start.Main ++StopParams=--stop
```

Remember to run cmd.exe as administrator to the command take effect.

Answer (score 2):

You can run as a Windows service Jetty can be used to exewrap.
 
Jetty Windows Service all-in-one packages are also distributed.

http://exewrap.sourceforge.jp/jetty/

Answer (score 1):

If you are in a bit of a locked down environment and need to stay within the Microsoft provided tool set, then `srvany`, `instsrv` and `sc` are your friends.  Unfortunately it often  includes making registry edits.  The nice thing is it's very flexible.

Here's what I did recently to auto-start a Selenium Grid hub server.

---

Copy `srvany.exe` into `c:\tools\srvany\srvany.exe`

Open cmd window as admin and run:

```
$ cd C:\tools\srvany
$ sc create "Selenium Grid Hub Server" binPath= c:\tools\srvany\srvany.exe DisplayName= "Selenium Grid Hub Server"
```

**RegEdit**

`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\Selenium Grid Hub Server`

Add a new key named `Parameters`
Under that key, add 3 new String Values named:

- `Application` => `${JAVA_HOME}/bin/java.exe`
- `AppParameters` => `-jar selenium-server-standalone-2.42.2.jar -role hub`
- `AppDirectory` => `C:\tools\selenium`

---

Credit for this goes to http://codeforjava.blogspot.com/2010/12/run-java-application-as-windows-nt.html