# Running jetty+solr on Windows server

Tags: java, windows, service, solr, jetty

I am trying to create service for Windows.

I have .bat script that launches jetty with solr:

```
cd ../jetty
java -Djetty.home="C:/Webs/lrt-archyvas/jetty" -Djava.ext.dirs="C:/Webs/lrt-archyvas/parts/jetty-download/lib;C:/Webs/lrt-archyvas/parts/jetty-download/lib/jsp" -jar C:/Webs/lrt-archyvas/parts/jetty-download/start.jar C:/Webs/lrt-archyvas/jetty/etc/jetty.xml C:/Webs/lrt-archyvas/jetty/etc/jetty-deploy.xml C:/Webs/lrt-archyvas/jetty/etc/jetty-webapps.xml OPTIONS=Server,jmx,resources,websocket,ext,plus,annotations
```

I want to create service and in that case I want to use this http://drupal.org/node/1359598 tutorial.

Problem is that I can't use `cd` and go into jetty directory. I have to set it in parameters but I am unable to.

When I run this script from other directory I get the following:

```
2012-03-02 13:04:51.493:INFO::jetty-7.3.1.v20110307
2012-03-02 13:04:51.511:INFO::Deployment monitor C:\Webs\lrt-archyvas\bin\webapp
s at interval 1
2012-03-02 13:04:51.538:INFO::Started SelectChannelConnector@0.0.0.0:8080
```

It uses "C:\Webs\lrt-archyvas\bin\" (cwd) as jetty.home to load webapps. And I set it to `C:/Webs/lrt-archyvas/jetty`.

How can I override this?

Comment: Running Solr as a Tomcat app will save you some headache :-/ http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrTomcat#Single_Solr_app

Answer (score 1):

You can set jetty.home on the java commandline with -Djetty.home="C:\foo"

(you also ought to use windows paths for that to work I suspect, hence the backslashes)

the jetty start mechanism should pick this setting up and operate from there

I should add that since this is jetty 7 apparently being used there ought to be a start.ini file somewhere in there that you should be able to specify the options and xml files on.  You can use the --dry-run option to have the actual option string that is being used.

If you experiment with --dry-run you should be able to iron out the precise string to drop into that service window for things to work.  That ought to take some of the tedious process out of determining the correct string.

cheers

Comment: Right, and that's what I do. I set -Djetty.home to various paths and it doesn't pick those up. I tried `\ `, `/`, quoted, unquoted, etc.. Nothing seemed to work and `/` was my last attempt

Comment: edited the message a bit, look around for that start.ini file and experiment with --dry-run some, that ought to get you going, otherwise point me at the distribution that is leveraging jetty and I'll take a look at what they are doing.  The syntax references is from jetty6 and things have evolved a fair amount since then.

Comment: Seems like your answer wast most reasonable. I'll award you the bounty.

Answer (score 0):

I fear not being very helpful ...
Could you give us more details ?
What kind of software are you trying to use to set your application as a Windows service.
Don't know if you can afford to use this product but it's a very good one : 
[tutorial article](http://edn.embarcadero.com/article/32068)
[download page](http://wrapper.tanukisoftware.com/doc/english/download.jsp)

Have you edited the start.config Jetty file ? I guess it may be confused by a wrong location of the jar file (jetty home is computed like this in Jetty)....

HTH
Jerome

Comment: As mentioned in tutorial I gave link to I'm trying to use http://nssm.cc/ which is pretty simple to set up. You just need to write command line to run your software. I have not edited start.config (and there is no such file, probably because it's older version of jetty (7.3.1)).

Comment: the start.config file is located inside of the start.jar file

Answer (score 0):

You can try using procrun from Apache Commons Daemon project. Following post has lot of details.

[Running Jetty 7 as Windows Service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2094429/running-jetty-7-as-windows-service)

Answer (score 0):

You can be easily run as a Windows service Solr can be used to exewrap.
 
Solr Windows Service all-in-one packages are also distributed.

http://exewrap.sourceforge.jp/solr/