# ClassNotFoundException while running Jetty 7.6 as a windows service

Tags: windows, service, jetty

I went through the solution written by @crowne for the question:
[Running Jetty 7 as Windows Service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2094429/running-jetty-7-as-windows-service)

The command I used to install service:

> bin\JettyService //IS//JettyService --DisplayName="Jetty Service"
>   --Install=D:\Jetty-7.6\bin\JettyService.exe --LogPath=D:\Jetty-7.6\logs --LogLevel=Debug --StdOutput=auto --StdError=auto --StartMode=Java --StopMode=Java --Jvm=auto ++JvmOptions=-Djetty.home=D:\Jetty-7.6 ++JvmOptions=-DSTOP.PORT=8087 ++JvmOptions=-DSTOP.KEY=downB0y ++JvmOptions=-Djetty.logs=D:\Jetty-7.6\logs ++JvmOptions=-Dorg.eclipse.jetty.util.log.SOURCE=true ++JvmOptions=-XX:MaxPermSize=128M ++JvmOptions=-XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled ++JvmOptions=-XX:+CMSPermGenSweepingEnabled --Classpath=D:\Jetty-7.6\start.jar --StartClass=org.eclipse.jetty.start.Main ++StartParams=OPTIONS=All ++StartParams=D:\Jetty-7.6\etc\jetty.xml ++StartParams=D:\Jetty-7.6\etc\jetty-deploy.xml ++StartParams=D:\Jetty-7.6\etc\jetty-webapps.xml ++StartParams=D:\Jetty-7.6\etc\jetty-contexts.xml ++StartParams=D:\Jetty-7.6\etc\jetty-testrealm.xml --StopClass=org.eclipse.jetty.start.Main ++StopParams=--stop

but I get this error when starting the jetty server:

> 2013-06-03 14:58:17 Commons Daemon procrun stderr initialized
>   java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/eclipse/jetty/start/Main
>
> Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   org.eclipse.jetty.start.Main
>
> at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
>
> at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>
> at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
>
> at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
>
> at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
>
> at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
>
> Could not find the main class: org.eclipse.jetty.start.Main.  Program
>   will exit.
>
> Exception in thread "main"

I am using Windows 7, 32 bit and Jetty 7.6. Can someone please help me out.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like the issue was with the prunsrv.exe provided with the commons daemon binaries. I then used the 64 bit .exe provided on a 64 bit windows system and it worked just fine. but why id did not work on 32 bit windows is still a mystery

Answer (score 0):

It would appear that you have a classpath issue where the service running java execution does not know about the start.jar file.  I would look into whatever options are available on that service dealio and figure out how to add something like

```
-cp d:\Jetty-7.6\start.jar
```

so it is on your classpath, from that point on the Jetty start.jar process should craft a reasonable classpath.

Comment: I have put start.jar in the classpath using :  --Classpath=D:\Jetty-7.6\start.jar, but then also while starting the server its not able to find the class.