# Required to Run Jetty server as a service which should availabe in services.msc and auto started

Tags: java, jetty

Hello request you to please guide to start on requirement to runn a Jetty server as a Service
and running Jetty as a NT Service in windows environment

so user directlly can able to login web application on the startup of the services in any operating system.

Regards,
Mohasin.

Answer (score 0):

The [Java Service Wrapper](http://wrapper.tanukisoftware.com/doc/english/product-overview.html) (commercial product) can be used to take any java application and make a Linux or Windows service out of it:

> The Java Service Wrapper enables a Java Application to be run as a
>   Windows Service or UNIX Daemon. It also monitors the health of your
>   Application and JVM.

You'll find that on Linux it is more difficult as there isn't any standard way of doing startup scripts.  You'll need to create startup scripts for each of the major ways of doing it.

There is another stack overflow question that shows how to do this on Windows using a free Apache licensed project:  [Running Jetty 7 as Windows Service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2094429/running-jetty-7-as-windows-service)

Comment: Be aware that Java Service Wrapper is a commercial product, with non-open source license and costs.